# NX generate fails with undefined paths property

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I have updated my project, from angular 10 to 11, and then to the latest version of nrwl and nx Cli.

All things fixed and now trying to create new libs using:
`ng generate @nrwl/angular:library --name=mylib --directory=data --no-interactive --dry-run`

The problem is it returns the error *Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined*
According to https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3251 it is related to the name of tsconfig, which Nx is expecting to be tsconfig.base.json. I searched my project for reference of this file and found none, so I don't understand why the generate command is trying to find it.

As per some of the comments on the above issue, renaming the file to tsconfig.base.json will make the ng generate work again, but that is just a workaround in my opinion.

Has anyone faced this issue, and if yes, found a way to correct it?

Comment: I have faced similar issue, You could workaround this by setting  --publishable flag to true

Comment: tried that. It asked for the `importPath` and when I provided it, the same was throw

Comment: We were able to fix by setting --publishable flag. Try using nx dev tool?